# Why is the .NET null conditional operator not returning false when trying to check if a collection has any items?

Tags: c#, .net, null-conditional-operator

I'm trying to do the following check:

```
if (result?.Pets?.Any() == false) { ... }
```

and if `result == null` .. then it's not going inside the scope of that `if` check.

I thought that `result?.` will (in this case) return `null` .. so is this then trying to do:

```
if (null == false) { ... } // result == null
```

and if that is the case .. then what? My first thought was something like this:

```
if (result?.Pets?.Any() == false ?? false) { .. }
```

but that is a compiler error :(

Comment: evaluate by `result?.Pets?.Any() != true` for null or empty.

Comment: If `result` is `null`, or `result.Pets` is `null` then `result?.Pets?.Any()` will evaluate as `null`. `null == false` will evaluate as `false` because `null` and `false` are not the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have explained, null does not equal false. Using the null-coalescing operator `??` to get around this should work but your syntax is incorrect. The correct syntax would be something like this:

```
if ((result?.Pets?.Any() ?? false) == false) { ... }
```

However, for readability, I would go for something like this:

```
bool petsFound = result?.Pets?.Any() ?? false;
if (!petsFound) { ... }
```

Alternatively, you could do it the good old way using a null check and the short-circuiting `||` operator:

```
if (result?.Pets is null || !result.Pets.Any()) { ... }
```

Comment: Cheers and awesome. I really like the 2nd solution also because I'm a big fan of readability (support/maintenance of an app, etc). So this works nicely, also. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 3):

`null` doesn't equal `false`, nor does `null` equal `true`. The simple way to fix this is to check if the result of `?.Any()` *isn't* `true` (ie `null` *or* `false`).

```
if (result?.Pets?.Any() != true) { ... }
```

Comment: Its also an indicator that you should check for null and handle that case separately.

Comment: Yes, but it depends. Sometimes you want the same logic to occur if you have null _or_ you have no results.